# Code first validation that requires database access (duplicate valies)

Tags: validation, attributes, code-first

This question may have already been asked, sorry

I'm looking at the architecture for validating our model. Our simple validation can be achieved by using the property validation attributes (some custom) and using

ModelState.IsValid

however the problem is when validation requires access to the database or access to another property. A perfect example is to check for duplicate names. In this case we need to check the database for duplicate names where the id is not equal to that of the current object (for updates)

If we were to write this as an validation attribute to be applied to the name property this would cause to problems. Ome how do we get access to the database and two how would we get access to the id property.

So in conclusion. Is there any examples of good ways to architect a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time exploring this today for a project I was working on and came to these conclusions.

It is not to bad to solve the how, much of it involves some reflection and using the validation context to inspect and access other properties of your model or using IValidationObject. The real question becomes is it okay to do validation that requires database interaction.

For one I was concerned about performance, in one particular case a validation made a query that returned an object to ensure it existed which I later needed for relationship assignment which would then cause another query.

Secondly you need to think about database concurrency. The best way to do duplication checks is during insert not before because the database could change between the two operations. This also relates to the first reason, an object could be deleted immediately after a database reported it exists.

In my particular project I felt it better to keep this sort of behavior with modifying my EF context and adding anything that went wrong to the ModelState.